# Specgram Analysis

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, speech-recognition

I have a project on audio matching using matlab. So, there's a couple of correct and wrong sound files. Each correct file is the voice of a person saying "4,6,8". Each wrong file has different sequences of number such as "6,4,8" or "4,8,6". I'm supposed to detect with matlab if the right sequence has been said. So, if the correct sound is played I have to display "ACCEPTED" and if the wrong sound is played I have to display "NOT ACCEPTED".

I know I'm supposed to do a time frequency analysis of each correct sound and recognise a pattern. Then, I could simply put a frequency threshold for each time interval. EG: From 0.1 second to 0.9 second if the frequency is 1KHz then display "ACCEPTED".

But, I don't know how exactly to write a program for this. Plus, how do I get an accurate value for the frequency of each number in the time frequency analysis?

This is my code so far for the specgram

```
[right1, Fs] = wavread('C:\Users\Fazrina\Downloads\CorrectSequence1');

figure (1)

subplot(2,1,1), plot(right1), axis('tight');

subplot(2,1,2), specgram(right1,512,Fs);
```

Comment: a simple thresholding might not be sufficient. You might want to look at some machine learning algorithms for classification tasks. First you need to do feature extraction ([MFCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum) and the like)

Comment: The peak frequency from an FFT, or even the fundamental pitch which can be different, isn't what differentiates words.  You will have to examine more of the complete spectrum where each vowel may contain lots of frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a trivial case of matching spectrogram images. Looking at the spectrogram analysis alone, you're on a mission to fail due to many factors. If you don't want to go into the mirky depths of HMM analysis, then dynamic time warping is about as simple as you can get with reliable results. [Dan Ellis](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/ln/labrosa/matlab/dtw/) has some neat Matlab stuff on this.

Comment: +1 DTW can be used as a distance function in a simple nearest neighbor classifier